# How can I trim the output of an xpath query which feeds into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I am scraping the webpage at http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1

The full Code for this is at https://gist.github.com/3156035

The webpage uses old fashioned html tables without CSS so I used xpath to find certain keywords (clues) and then targeted the next element down. the keywords then feed into the following loop

```
clues.each do |clue|
  #putting the output into quotes, incase the content contains a comma!
  csv_text << "\"#{doc.at_xpath("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip}\""
  csv_text << ", " unless clues.last == clue
end
```

Since the array separates the values using a `,` I can add each value to its own cell in a csv, this works fine but the cell Warranty reads "1 year, pick-up and return, parts and labour"

The code is chopping that up and putting it into 3 cells :
"1 year" then "pick-up and return" and then "parts and labour"

What I want is for it to keep it as a single cell: 
"1 year, pick-up and return, parts and labour"

How can I change the code to *not* match commas within cells?

Comment: So, what is the question? There isn't one. What is the exact wanted result? None specified.

Comment: Its clearly written above what I need to do, code is included.

Comment: Ninja2k, What you need to do is a *statement* -- not a question. Also, the fact that you have provided a link to your code doesn't change the fact that you haven't provided the wanted output.

Comment: @Ninja2k you're new to SO, but it is generally the accepted practice to ask a specific question and include exact desired output for the given input, or at least sample output. You'll get a better response if you do.

Comment: Sorry I am not a programmer, the question has been re edited as best I can explain it, please be patient. Thank you.

Comment: Ninja2k, Enclose each value in quotes.

Comment: Hi Dimitre I am not sure I understand your answer? which values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing part is that you're posing this as a Nokogiri question, when you are really asking how to create a proper CSV.

I would recommend using the CSV library:

```
CSV.open("path/to/output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  #loop here over all your pages to scrape
    csv << clues.map{|clue| doc.at("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip}
  #end loop
end
```

This will automatically create valid CSV with any comma-containing entries properly quoted.

Comment: Thanks ever so much for that Mark!